# Maximum value from contiguous part of a list

Tags: python-3.x

How can I find maximum value from a part of list. Means if I want to know maximum number from index i to j then is there any in built method to do so.

Comment: Where is your code so we can help you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example, define a list with five elements, print the max from the second until the third index.

[max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) is a built-in function.

**max:**

> Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more
>   arguments.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
print (max(l[2:3]))
```